# Silly Error that's killing me. Method Range of Object failed lol

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have these two lines of code. Both are range variables, set the same way using the same variables for `lastrow` and `lastcol` both hold the correct values. The worksheets are in the same workbook. The first range is set fine. The second throws an error. `Method 'Range' of Object '_Worksheet' failed.`. As you can see I am trying to set the range values equal.  I feel like this error normally occurs because the range isn't fully qualified...any ideas here?

```
Set csvrng = mm.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcol - 2))
Set wksrng = wks.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcol - 2))

csvrng.Value = wksrng.Value
```

Also tried:

```
mm.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcol - 2)) = wks.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcol - 2))
```

Also used the `.value` for each range. Same error on the `wks` worksheet each time.

UPDATE:
`ActiveSheet` will not solve this since I have worksheet variables set. @Ike was dead on though. I needed to fully qualify my `Cells` reference.

Comment: You should reference `Cells` explicitly: `mm.Cells` and `wks.Cells`. How do `lastRow`and `lastCol` look like - what ist the base sheet they are looking at?

Comment: That's the answer. explicit cell reference. Silly rookie mistake! Thanks @Ike

Comment: Also doesn't have anything to do with the active sheet since I have workbook variables set. Can I un-associate this question?

Comment: You should ** always** avoid implicit references - it nearly always causes errors that are very hard to find.